# How do I complete exercise 3 from "Art & Science of Java", Chapter 4?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that reads in a positive int, and then calculates and displays the sum of the first N odd ints. For example, if N is 4, the program should display the value 16, which is 1 + 3 + 5 + 7.

Here's what I have so far, but I've come up against a brick wall, and would appreciate a point in the right direction.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class OddIntegers extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        println("This program adds the number of odd numbers");
        int n = readInt("Enter a positive number: ");
        int b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++);
            b = b + (b + 2);

        println("The total is " + b);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: math says the answer is `N*N`.

Comment: Voting to close as part of the homework tag cleanup.

Comment: Leaving the homework tag in until closed.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `i` for [aggregating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aggregating):

```
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b += (2*i + 1);
}
```

Input 4, Result: 16

Answer (score 2):

First remove `;` from the end of `for` loop.

Second use `sum` as a variable to store sum and `b` to keep odd numbers.

```
int b=1, sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
    sum+=b;
    b+=2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon right after your for loop so there is no actual code in the loop, also you calculation is wrong, you add an extra value because you start `b` at one.

```
int b = 0;
int odd = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    b = b + odd;
    odd += 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Its amazing how much of a difference a semi-colon here or some brackets there can make!